# Como fazer return URL automático no paypal

Tags: api

Tenho uma página com um formulário que, após submetido, envia os dados para o paypal, depois do cliente fazer o pagamento queria que o mesmo fosse redirecionado para o url de retorno que envio junto com esse formulário, no entanto, sempre que o cliente faz o pagamento é enviado para uma página que diz que finalizou o pagamento e o cliente apenas e redirecionado para o url que indico se clicar no link que diz "Clique Aqui para voltar para ...". mas eu queria que ele fosse logo para a pagina que em 10 seg é redirecionado

Segue o o ecrã que queria que saltasse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho o Return URL ativo e configurado no site do paypal

Eu queria que o utilizador depois de pagar fosse logo reencaminhado para esta página, sendo assim redirecionado diretamente para o site.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Faça o login na sua conta do Paypal e ative o "Auto Return".

Normalmente encontrará em "Payment Preferences" (Selling Preferences).

Há um campo para inserir uma URL de retorno. Pode colocar qualquer URL pois essa URL pode ser customizada nas requisições de pagamento.

**Os parâmetros do checkout**

```
return -> URL absoluta da página de retorno
rm -> 1: GET, 2: POST
custom -> parametro_que_vc_quer_receber=valor_desse_parametro
```

Exemplo

```
return: http://foo.bar/order/paypal/return
rm: 2
custom: order_id=10
```

Isso informará ao Paypal para que retorne pelo método POST `(rm == 2)` e inclua um parâmetro `order_id` com valor `10`. A URL que receberá é `http://foo.bar/order/paypal/return`

Para mais referências (inglês): https://www.paypal.com/be/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside

**IPN Listener**

Para reforçar, é recomendável definir também a URL de notificação.

O parâmetro é `notify_url`. Para saber mais, consulte: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/

Comment: Olá, obigado pela disponibildiade, no entanto eu tenho isso configurado, mas sempre que faço um pagamento o utilizador tem de carregar no link para voltar ao site. depois disso vai para a pagina que diz que em 10 seg vai ser reencaminhado. eu queria que o utilizador após pagar fosse logo reencaminhado para o site sem ter de clicar no link

Comment: Você se refere aquele pequeno delay, certo? Não tem muito o que fazer. Pelo menos eu desconheço um redirecionamento instantâneo. O Paypal usa aquele pequeno delay. Acho que é para que o usuário tenha um tempo para poder ver que a transação foi feita, mas dentro do domínio do Paypal.

Comment: não,  eu não falo desse delay, falo da primeira imagem da minha pergunta em que o utilizador fica ali e apenas e reencaminhado para o site se clicar no link. 
Apos clicar no link e enviado então para aquela pagina que tem o delay em que espera ate 10 seg e so depois e redirecionado para o meu site, o